# Asp.Net Error Message in Event Viewer:Unable to validate data

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003, viewstate, web-config

We have a Asp.Net Webform page which contains a GridView inside UpdatePanel and refreshes every minute. And every one minute we get the following error in Event log.

```
Error Message:Unable to validate data.
Stack Trace:   at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.GetDecodedData(Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Int32& dataLength)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString).
```

We have tried the following.

1. Adding a static machine key in the Web.Config. (Did not work?)
2. Disabling the View State Mac in the Web,.Config using following entry. (Did not work)

> ```
> <pages buffer="true" enableViewStateMac="false">
> ```

Is there something else that might cause this?

**Update:** We get this error only on the Live Server. Not on Test or Dev server.

Comment: Did you find the cause of this I am getting the same issue? Please help!